# how to determine the size of a putty window

Tags: putty

I would like to open three putty session and align them horizontally. By default the columns is 80 but I can't fit 3 putty side by side. So I maximized one of them and type

```
tput cols
```

the result is 237. I divide 237 by 3 and it gaves me 79. Still dont fit. I just realise this is due to the fact there is a border + a scrollbar in each window. How to calculate the size of the scrollbar + the border?

Comment: Windows has had an automatic "tile horizontally" function for many years, hasn't it?

Comment: this features (in task manager) has been removed from Windows 8 (I don't know if it's back in Windows 10)

Comment: Even if you right-click the taskbar?